# Avoid text if will not fit in page

Tags: page-breaking

Some time ago I posted a question regarding forcing creation of a new page if a paragraph will break because of the pages limits. This was solved by an answer that worked perfectly. However, instead of breaking the text into a new page, is it possible to ignore it completely? What it mean is, is it possible to skip the whole paragraph if it will not fit?

Here the current code (sorry for the weird definitions)

```
\newcommand{\uComment}[3]{%
  \filbreak
  \begin{commentTextFont}#1\end{commentTextFont}%
  \vspace*{0.5cm}
  \begin{userFont}\textit{#2}\hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{dateFont}#3\end{dateFont}\end{userFont}%
  \vspace*{0.8cm}
}


%------------------------
% Invoke Packages
%------------------------

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}

%------------------------
% Set Dimensions
%------------------------
\usepackage[ 
  paperwidth = 168.3mm,
  paperheight = 260.4mm,
  top = 6mm,
  bottom = 7mm,
  outer = 6mm,
  inner = 20mm
]{geometry}

%------------------------
% Remove indentation from all paragraphs
%------------------------
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% Comments
\newcommand{\CommentFontSize}{21}
\newcommand{\CommentSkipMult}{25}
% Author
\newcommand{\UserFontSize}{16}
\newcommand{\UserSkipMult}{0}
% Date
\newcommand{\DateFontSize}{15}
\newcommand{\DateSkipMult}{0}

% Comments
\newenvironment{commentTextFont}
 {\fontfamily{mdugm}%
  \fontsize{\CommentFontSize}{\CommentSkipMult}%
  \selectfont}
 {\par}
% Author
\newenvironment{userFont}
 {\fontfamily{mdugm}%
  \fontsize{\UserFontSize}{\UserSkipMult}%
  \selectfont}
 {\par}
% Date
\newenvironment{dateFont}
 {\fontfamily{mdugm}%
  \fontsize{\DateFontSize}{\DateSkipMult}%
  \selectfont}
 {\par}

%------------------------
% Set commands 
%------------------------

\newcommand{\uComment}[3]{%
  \filbreak
  \begin{commentTextFont}#1\end{commentTextFont}%
  \vspace*{0.5cm}
  \begin{userFont}\textit{#2}\hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{dateFont}#3\end{dateFont}\end{userFont}%
  \vspace*{0.8cm}
}

%------------------------
% Document
%------------------------

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\uComment{\lipsum[73]}{someone}{2000}
\uComment{\lipsum[75]}{someone}{2000}
\uComment{\lipsum[66]}{someone}{2000}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just to clarify, you want any occurrence of `\uComment{..}{..}{..}` to just disappear, never to be seen again, in case the current page overflows? And  then what - terminate the document, or go on with the next `\uComment` until the next page overflows?

Comment: Yes, indeed, disappear if it will overflow. Then go on with the next \uComment.

Comment: No one has any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is one idea. I have omitted your font customisation etc. and only addressed the problem of dropping paragraphs that would break across two pages. The argument of `\printifspace` will go onto the current page if there is enough space left; otherwise, it will be dropped.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern,calc,ifthen,pgffor}

% determine how much space is left on the current page
\newcommand*\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\boxheight}

% put content in a savebox to determine if it fits onto the page. 
% if it does, typeset it; if not, ignore it and move on to next page.
\newcommand{\printifspace}[1]{%
    \sbox{\mybox}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1\par\medskip\par}}%
    \setlength{\boxheight}{\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}%
    \ifthenelse{\boxheight<\measurepage}%
        {\usebox{\mybox}\par}%
        {\typeout{dropped an overflowing chunk}\clearpage}%
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2,...,20}{\printifspace{\x: \lipsum[\x]}}

\end{document}
```

With the default settings for margins and font sizes (at least on my system), the 5th, 11th and 17th paragraph will be dropped.

Comment: You probably don't need to store the content in a box, as you can just `\settoheight{\boxheight}{...}`.

Comment: @Werner - I don't see how that would work, but feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael! Although I had something different I mind, should have explained it better. What I meant is if it could just omit the text that does not fit and try the next one, but never moving on to the next page. So if there's 3 \uComment objects from my original example, add them one by one and if one will not fit, omit it and try the next one, but **never** move to the next page. What do you think?

Comment: @DarienBrito -- I think this is a strange request ;-) Just omitting the `\clearpage` from the code my answer should give you the desired effect.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Perfect, that works great! Sorry about the strange request, I'm working on a strange project :D